# ASP.NET Role Management, How does that work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My ASP.NET application allows users to login and access certain information from the website. These users are basically belonging to multiple roles e.g: I have roles like "Administrators", "Power Users" and "Guests". The users are allowed to modify or view data on the .aspx page as per their roles. I read through about Role Management in ASP.NET on MSN. What I could figure out is that the pages related to each role are sorted into a separate folder, i.e I need to have sub folders like "Administrators", "Power Users" and "Guests". So when a user logs in he is redirected to the pages in the role he belongs to. Am I right?
Here the drawback is that if I need to make some changes to the Administrator folder, I will as well need to make the same changes to other folders.
This would make it very cumbersome and difficult to track sometimes. Is there some other way we can do this?
Thanks & Regards,
Sarin Gopalan

Answer (score 0):

Well you can manage it by separating user specific functionality into specific controller i.e. AdminController, UserController.

You can extract out functions that are not user specific into a common controller and access directly from there.

Additionally Authorize attribute can be applied on controller or even on method. It will allow you to have a fine grained control over who can access a method in a controller.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN, Sales Admin")]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response... Sorry, I am not on MVC! Any other ...way?

Comment: What are you using then? Can you please update tag in your post. And also add more information in your question.

Comment: I am using web forms on each of the folders. Hence why, I am facing the problem of duplication with minor differences between them on each of the folders...